# Log probability of compound Poisson distribution

Tags: distributions

Does anyone know how can I find the analytic and numerical log probability of compound Poisson distribution implemented in mathematica?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundPoissonDistribution.html

Comment: What do you mean by log probability? Please give its definition.

Comment: You need more details.  Is there a specific distribution of interest?  I assume that you've noticed that `CompoundPoissonDistribution` rarely (if ever) returns a PDF.  I think you'll just need to specify a distribution and use the definition of a pdf for a compound distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the particular distribution of interest and apply the definition of a pdf for a compound distribution.  (Note that `PDF` and `CDF` are not mentioned as working with `CompoundDistribution`:  just `Mean`, `Variance`, and `RandomVariate`.)

Here's an example using a Binomial distribution:

```
pdf[y_, λ_, n_, p_] := Sum[Binomial[k  n, y] p^y  (1 - p)^(k  n - y) PDF[PoissonDistribution[λ], k],
 {k, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {n ∈ PositiveIntegers, 0 < p < 1, λ > 0}]

pdf[0, \[Lambda], n, p]
(* E^((-1 + (1 - p)^n) λ) *)

pdf[3, λ, n, p]
(* -(1/6) E^-λ n (1 - p)^(-3 + n) p^3 λ (-2 E^(λ + (-1 + (1 - p)^n) λ) + 
   3 E^(λ + (-1 + (1 - p)^n) λ) n - E^((1 - p)^n λ) n^2 + 
   3 E^(λ + (-1 + (1 - p)^n) λ) n (1 - p)^n λ - 
   3 E^((1 - p)^n λ) n^2 (1 - p)^n λ - E^((1 - p)^n λ) n^2 (1 - p)^(2 n) λ^2)]
```

Comment: Your assumptions do not appear to be consistent with `DistributionParameterAssumptions[BinomialDistribution[n, p]]`?

Comment: @BobHanlon Those assumptions weren't meant to match.  I restricted things to $n>0$ and $0<p<1$ rather than $n \geq 0$ and $0 \leq p \leq 1$ to avoid degenerate cases which can sometimes cause errors.